# Exchange 2010 PushSubscription WCF SOAP

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, exchange-server, ews-managed-api

I'm trying to use the PushSubscription feature of Exchange 2010.  So far I've got the code to setup push on Exchange 2010:

```
ExchangeService esService = new ExchangeService();
esService.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "pass", "domain");
esService.Url = new Uri("https://exchange-box-2010/ews/exchange.asmx");

PushSubscription ps = esService.SubscribeToPushNotificationsOnAllFolders(new Uri("http://192.168.1.102:8080/FinWorkFlow"), 1, null, EventType.NewMail, EventType.Copied);
```

I've also got a WCF service that run's at http://192.168.1.102:80/FinWorkFlow with a tcp tracing utility redirecting from 8080 to 80.  The traces indicate that Exchange sends out a request to http://192.168.1.102:8080/FinWorkFlow and that a good response is sent from my WCF service.  However the SendNotificationResponseType parameter of the SendNotification method is always null:

```
SendNotificationResultType INotificationServiceBinding.SendNotification(SendNotificationResponseType request)
        {
            if(request != null && request.ResponseMessages != null)
            {
                foreach(ResponseMessageType messsage in request.ResponseMessages.Items)
                {
                    if(messsage.ResponseCode != ResponseCodeType.NoError)
                    {
                        return CreateNotificationResult(SubscriptionStatusType.Unsubscribe);
                    }

                    SendNotificationResponseMessageType mtNotificationMessage = (SendNotificationResponseMessageType)messsage;
                    NotificationType ntNotification = mtNotificationMessage.Notification;
                    string strSubscriptionId = ntNotification.SubscriptionId;

                    for(int i = 0; i < ntNotification.Items.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if(ntNotification.ItemsElementName[i].ToString() == "NewMailEvent")
                        {
                            BaseObjectChangedEventType bocet = (BaseObjectChangedEventType)ntNotification.Items[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return CreateNotificationResult(SubscriptionStatusType.OK);
        }
```

The interface is defined as:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.42")]
[System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "NotificationServiceBinding", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(ServiceConfiguration))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(DirectoryEntryType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(TargetFolderIdType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(RecurrenceRangeBaseType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(RecurrencePatternBaseType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(AttachmentType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BasePermissionType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BaseItemIdType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BaseEmailAddressType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BaseFolderIdType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BaseFolderType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BaseResponseMessageType))]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages", ConfigurationName = "Microsoft.Exchange.Notifications.INotificationServicePortType")]
public interface INotificationServiceBinding
{

    /// <remarks/>
    [OperationContract(Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*")]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute()]
    [System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/SendNotification", Use = System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Bare)]
    [return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages")]
    SendNotificationResultType SendNotification([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SendNotification", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages")] SendNotificationResponseType SendNotification1);
}
```

A typical request from Exchange is:

```
POST /FinWorkFlow HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages/SendNotification
Host: 192.168.1.102:8080
Content-Length: 1486
Connection: Close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap11:Envelope xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap11:Header><RequestServerVersion xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="Exchange2010" /></soap11:Header><soap11:Body><m:SendNotification xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"><m:ResponseMessages><m:SendNotificationResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success"><m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode><m:Notification><t:SubscriptionId>EgBiZnQtbWVybGluLnJibS5sYW4QAAAAz4lScRmxbEaLeCfsAFRDmEswGeTtJs0I</t:SubscriptionId><t:PreviousWatermark>AQAAAOUSjqlc3mdHh1LhIiuqSBc1UCgAAAAAAAA=</t:PreviousWatermark><t:MoreEvents>false</t:MoreEvents><t:NewMailEvent><t:Watermark>AQAAAOUSjqlc3mdHh1LhIiuqSBc8UCgAAAAAAAE=</t:Watermark><t:TimeStamp>2010-09-20T15:16:28Z</t:TimeStamp><t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGVmOWI3OGE5LWJmMjEtNDU4Mi1hY2JlLTdhYzZmMGQ2N2Q4ZABGAAAAAACd5Nq062e3ToqPr4+g8e/UBwDjUS8vlMohRaUyr3p641BAACy83CEfAABwOzEV48hOQJYkk18qYDCqAAAAnG3SAAA=" ChangeKey="CQAAAA==" /><t:ParentFolderId Id="AAMkAGVmOWI3OGE5LWJmMjEtNDU4Mi1hY2JlLTdhYzZmMGQ2N2Q4ZAAuAAAAAACd5Nq062e3ToqPr4+g8e/UAQDjUS8vlMohRaUyr3p641BAACy83CEfAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAAA==" /></t:NewMailEvent></m:Notification></m:SendNotificationResponseMessage></m:ResponseMessages></m:SendNotification></soap11:Body></soap11:Envelope>
```

Can anyone explain why the body of the SOAP request is not being picked up and put into the SendNotificationResponseType variable?

Comment: Does this mechanism supports notifications when a new mail is arriving to the mailbox?
can i register for new mails event - once and receive the mails as soon as they are arriving to the device, without polling and sending a request to the server every few minutes..? i want to be able to handle the new mails instantly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

Turns out that I used the wsdl tool to build the interface - should have used svcutil.  This built an interface with the correct method attributes.